# img stretching not working

Tags: html, css, jsp

```
<div align="center">
    <img src="<%=image1%>" class="<%=imgSizeCss%>" />
</div>
<table border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="<%=header1%>">
                        SSSS</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div align="center">
                <img src="<%=image%>" class="<%=imgSimCss%>" />
            </div>
```

I have two divs.

The first div stretches img to **100%**.

The second div stretches img to **75%**.

But my second div is not working. Looks like image works, but not image1. How can I fix it?

Comment: you have provided half html. Pleas provide proper one.

Comment: your html is messed up please provide a complete formatted one

Comment: my apology, I was in a hurry that time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix it. As `div2` is within `table` , it is not working properly. So I just remove `div2` outside. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You said "number two", but your your code only has "image1" and "image". Maybe that's the problem?